# Is it possible to display multi-page, multi-layer TIFF images using javascript in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, tiff, libtiff, libtiff.net

We are thinking about a library which can get a TIFF image and display each page (frame) of TIFF file in a separate canvas element. Also some pages might have layers. We want to be able to show/hide layers at user's will.
It is not necessary to tell me the complete solution or library. Just tell me if it is possible to accomplish all these requirements by javascript or we need to get help of server-side programming?

Answer (score 1):

Should be possible. I don't think browsers support the TIFF format natively, but a quick Google search turns up [at least](https://github.com/GPHemsley/tiff-js) [two](https://github.com/seikichi/tiff.js/tree/master) TIFF parsers for JavaScript. From there on, you can display it in any way you like; tiff.js even has a [multipage demo](http://seikichi.github.io/tiff.js/multipage.html).

Comment: thanks a lot. Do you think we also can take layers and show/hide them at will.